# HTTPContext request/response destination URL (C#)

Tags: c#, asp.net, url, httphandler, httpcontext

There is an ASP.NET (C#) `HttpHandler` that handle requests for image files. I would like to know if its possible to determine WHERE these files are being displayed? Exact url (i.e. destination url address) of `WHERE` the images are shown.

e.g. 1: Are the requestor's showing them in an `img` tag on their website, or are they simply shown in a web browser as is (direct access)?

e.g. 2: If the image is going to be opened in a (target=blank) new window, then the url displayed is the same as the image url (i.e. hotlink), OR if the image is displayed in the requestor's website, the url will be the requestor's url.

Url Referrer in this case will be the same for both, so we can differentiate using Referrer.

Comment: It is not possible to determine WHY (img src vs browser address bar vs programmatic request) a specific request for a resource was made by a client. Even the HTTP referrer is unreliable as it can be tampered with.

Comment: grammar changes